# Selenium: webelement not interactable

Tags: angular, selenium, e2e

I'm doing an E2E test on an Angular/C# application with Selenium.

I want to fill in a angular material form with Selenium.

There are 2 form-fields: date1 and date2

Date1 works fine: I clear the field and fill in the new date:

```
public void Wait(IWebDriver _webDriver, string elementString)
{
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
   IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id(elementString) ));
} 

public void Test()
{
   Wait(_webDriver, "date1");
   for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
   webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("date1")).SendKeys(Keys.Backspace);
   }
   webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("date1")).SendKeys(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("d"));


}
```

HTML code:

```
<mat-form-field class="half-width-field">          
   <mat-label> date1</mat-label>
   <input matInput class="form-control"
      formControlName="date1"
      id=date1
      matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerEnd" 
      placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerEnd"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #pickerEnd></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-error *ngIf="updateProductForm.controls.date1.hasError('required')">
                      date1 is required
    </mat-error>   
    <mat-error *ngIf="updateProductForm.controls.date1.hasError('mismatch')">
              date1 must before due
    </mat-error>       
    </mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="half-width-field">          
   <mat-label> date2 </mat-label>
   <input matInput class="form-control"
      formControlName="date2"
      id=date2
      matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerStart" 
      placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerStart"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #pickerEnd></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-error *ngIf="updateProductForm.controls.date2.hasError('required')">
                       date2 is required
    </mat-error>   
    <mat-error *ngIf="updateProductForm.controls.date2.hasError('mismatch')">
              date2 must before due
    </mat-error>       
</mat-form-field>
```

When I try to do this with date2, I get a `NotInteractable` exception.

I use wait until visible (and tried also clickable and also a delay of 10 seconds.

`webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("date2")).Displayed` gives as result true?

What is going wrong?

Comment: can you share the url or html?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Clear()` method available for WebElement in Selenium - C# bindings.

So Instead of this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
   webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("date1")).SendKeys(Keys.Backspace);
   }
```

Simply remove the loop and use `Clear()` method

`webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("date1")).Clear()`

and since the second date input field is displayed. You can try to click first then clear it and then send the keys.

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("date2")).Click(); 
webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("date2")).Clear(); 
webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("date2")).SendKeys("New date here");
```

Comment: I know but Clear(), didn't work. Also in my other forms it doesn't work, that's why I did choose this solution. In other forms this for-loop workaround does work.

Comment: Solved, own problem, but with a workaround, using Tab keys (selenium interaction library).